# The acid in soft drinks dissolves your teeth. Which type of chemical could you use to stop the acid?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

The acid in soft drinks dissolves your teeth. Which type of chemical could you use to stop the acid?

Answer (score 2):

What you meant is known as erosion. Erosion is the chemical loss of enamel due to acid.When acid continuously attacks teeth, they cannot repair themselves and will gradually begin to turn fuzzy and dissolve. Most soft drinks contain acids such as citric, phosphoric and malic or tartaric acids. A study was done where extracted human teeth were placed in softdrinks. Within two days, the teeth became very soft and the enamel surface lost much of its calcium.

Brush your teeth at least twice a day with a fluoride-containing toothpaste.A mouth rinse containing fluoride can help prevent tooth decay, according to the American Dental Association. For children, sealants can be used.

Comment: Just this week I was talking to my dentist about this, and she said that it is recommended to wait at least 40 minutes after drinking acid beverages (like orange juice and wine) before brushing your teeth. If you brush them right afterwards, the teeth are still very fragile and erosion will be more signifcant, whereas waiting some time will provide enough time for some cleaning and recuperation. Also, there are erosion-specific toothpastes for those with these kinds of problems.

Comment: Yeah. There are lots of flourinated toothpaste(recommended for minimizing erosion) available. Likewise, as you have mentioned that we shouldnot brush before 40 min of intake of softdrinks and beverages, same goes for our daily meal as well.